# Operations on long numbers in R

Tags: r, long-integer, biginteger, bigdecimal

I aim to use maximum likelihood methods (usually about 10^5 iterations) with a probability distribution that creates very big integers and very small float values that cannot be stored as a `numeric` nor a in a `float` type.

I thought I would use the `as.bigq` in the `gmp` package. My issue is that one can only add, substract, multiply and dived two objects of class/type `bigq`, while my distribution actually contains logarithm, power, gamma and confluent hypergeometric functions.

What is my best option to deal with this issue?

- Should I use another package?
- Should I code all these functions for `bigq` objects.

  - Coding these function on R may cause some functions to be very slow, right?
  - How to write the logarithm function using only the `+,-,*,/` operators? Should I approximate this function using a taylor series expansion?
  - How to write the power function using only the `+,-,*,/` operators when the exponent is not an integer?
  - How to write the confluent hypergeometric function (the equivalent of the `Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[..]` function in `Mathematica`)?

I could eventually write these functions in `C` and call them from `R` but it sounds like some complicated work for not much, especially if I have to use the `gmp` package in C as well to handle these big numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your problems can be solved with `Rmpfr` most likely which allows you to use all of the functions returned by `getGroupMembers("Math")` with arbitrary accuracy.

Vignette:  http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/vignettes/Rmpfr-pkg.pdf

Simple example of what it can do:

```
test <- mpfr(rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=.0001), 240)

Reduce("*", test)
```

I don't THINK it has hypergeometric functions though...